# .bat file stuck at opening notepad document, not cancellable

Tags: batch-file, windows-console

As I write bat file very infrequently, every time I write a new one gets me a new problem.

I have a bat file that is suppose to open a txt file and open an URL (which is a concatenated string, using current date), something like:

```
@echo off
notepad "C:\Users\username\somefile.txt"
start chrome "https://domain.com/%DATE%?some=parameters"
```

The text file opens fine and then nothing happens - console window gets stuck, not responding to `ctrl-C`. Apparently batch is suspended waiting for the notepad part to complete, because when I close the txt file window chrome opens the URL.

I tried `< nul`, `> nul` for the notepad part, but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I see this correctly, you just need to use `start` with notepad also. It starts programs in another process so the script can continue.

```
@echo off
start notepad "C:\Users\username\somefile.txt"
start chrome "https://domain.com/%DATE%?some=parameters"
```

Comment: I seem to recall trying this as well, but... never mind. It works, thanks!